# how to generate in vhdl in my testbench using a procedure two signals with different frequencies and delays

Tags: vhdl, procedure, test-bench

I am currently trying to generate two signals in my testbench (VHDL) with a different delay, a different duty cycle and two different periods. The two signals must be carried out in parallel and not sequentially in a single main procedure containing the 6 parameters of the two signals (period1, delay1, duty cycle1, period2, delay2 and duty circle2). My problem is that the second signal is not activated at the desired moment but after the first signal has been exercised, which is logical since the execution is sequential. How can I get the second signal to activate at the desired Delay?

I've written two procedures for each signal and a main procedure for recalling them together. I hope to be able to have both signals activated at their respective delays independently of each other.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;

library work;
use work.all;

entity paralell is
end paralell;

architecture paralell_arch of paralell is

constant c_CLOCK_PERIOD : time := 40 ns;
signal  L1   : std_logic := '0';
signal  L2  : std_logic := '0';  
    
begin
    UUT : entity work.paralel
     port map (
       clk => r_CLOCK,
        sig1 => L1,
       sig2 =>  L2,
       
       );   
  p_CLK_GEN : process is
  begin
    wait for c_CLOCK_PERIOD/2;
    r_CLOCK <= not r_CLOCK;
  end process p_CLK_GEN;
```

````
Simulation : process   -- main testing
procedure parametre_2(T6 : time; D6 : time; Delay6 : time) is
  begin
    L2 <= '0';
    if Delay6 >= 0 ns then
    wait for Delay6;
    end if;
    L2 <= '1';
    wait for D6;
    L2 <= '0';
    wait for (T6 - D6);
  end procedure parametre_2;
  
  procedure parametre_1(T5 : time; D5 : time; Delay5 : time) is
        begin
          L1 <= '0';
        if Delay5 >= 0 ns then
          wait for Delay5;
        end if;
          L1 <= '1';
        if D5 >= 0 ns then
          wait for D5;
        end if;
          L1 <= '0';
          wait for (T5 - D5);
        end procedure parametre_1;
      ``` 
      ``` 
 procedure parametre(T3 : time; D3 : time; Delay1 : time; T4 : time; D4 :time; Delay2 : time)is
  begin
   for i in 0 to 1 loop
     if i = 0 then 
         parametre_1(T3, D3, Delay1);
          elsif i= 1 then
         parametre_2(T4, D4, Delay2);
         end if;
         end loop;
         
end procedure parametre;
begin
parametre(400 us, 200 us, 10 ns , 100 us , 50 us,20 ns);
  report " Simulation finished successfully!" severity note;
  wait;
end process;
end paralell_arch;
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing enough code for us to help you. -- Are you aware that VHDL is a **description** language, not a **programming** language? You can define as many processes you want.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?   I would try scheduling signal assignments using after (with a waveform - more than one edge) and using the VHDL attribute 'event.    Read up on both of those and then post what you come up with.  The procedure will also need the two signals as parameters

Comment: @thebusybee,  hello I post my code. Thank you

Comment: @JimLewis hi the code is above . thank you

Comment: If this is for a work project, then simply create two clocks separately.   Otherwise, did your code work?   I suggest your procedure has the clock as a output signal.  Then write `Clk <= transport '0' after HalfPeriod, '1' after ClockPeriod ; `.   Start both clocks at time zero by calling the procedure once for each clock.   Then for every other iteration find the rising edge of Clk and trigger the procedure again.   Try again with this information.

Comment: @JimLewis I can't get the clock to go out in this case I would have to overwrite the L1 L2 signals, I have at least tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code isn't a [mcve]. For example there is no declaration for r_CLOCK, DUT entity work.paralel is not provided and required to be found in the working library prior to analysis (compilation) of architecture paralell_arch of paralell. (the DUT instantiation can be commented out or removed as can the r_CLOCK assigning process). "How can I get the second signal to activate at the desired Delay?" The desired delay isn't immediately obvious. How about a specific question? The process final `wait;` statement prevents the clocks from occurring subsequently.

Comment: @user16145658  Nor is it producing the result the OP wanted.   But the OP did it to show they were trying.   I think something is amiss in the problem description as otherwise it is beyond the scope of a new person example

Comment: "My problem is that the second signal is not activated at the desired moment but after the first signal has been exercised, which is logical since the execution is sequential. How can I get the second signal to activate at the desired Delay?" What delay from what event or time? The question appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with Jim on the simpler approach but here is an alternative for scheduling all events from one process that scales well if there are many clocks:

```
architecture test of two_clocks_in_one_process is
  signal clocks : std_logic_vector(1 to 2) := "00";
  constant delays : time_vector(clocks'range) := (10 ns, 20 ns);
  constant high_widths : time_vector(clocks'range) := (200 ns, 50 ns);
  constant periods : time_vector(clocks'range) := (400 ns, 100 ns);
begin
  clock_driver : process is
    variable next_event : time_vector(clocks'range) := delays;
  begin
    wait for minimum(next_event) - now;
    for idx in clocks'range loop
      if now = next_event(idx) then
        clocks(idx) <= '1', '0' after high_widths(idx);
        next_event(idx) := now + periods(idx);
      end if;
    end loop;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Cool.   I would have said that there was no way to do it with `wait for`, and then you went and showed how to do it.   I still like the usage of `after` better as it uses VHDL as the scheduler - rather than writing your own scheduler in the code.

Comment: Yeah, I went for compactness and scalability in case there are many clocks and then vectorization and "wait for" became the solution. With "wait for" the initial delay is just an init value to the scheduler. It's possible to combine the internal scheduler with "wait for" and that would actually make the next_event assignment clearner. I'll update. With many signals I would also remove the aliases.

Answer (score 1):

First, for something that is not a college exercise, use two separate clock generators.   OSVVM library provides the following (see https://github.com/OSVVM/OsvvmLibraries).   Do the calls in the architecture, not a process.

```vhdl
osvvm.TbUtilPkg.CreateClock(Clk1, PERIOD_1, DUTY_CYCLE_1) ; 
osvvm.TbUtilPkg.CreateClock(Clk2, PERIOD_2, DUTY_CYCLE_2) ;
```

If for some reason a college exercise required me to dispatch these from the same process, I would do the following.  As an alternative to driving Clk1 and Clk2 to a '1' in the beginning of ClockProc, you could have initialized them to '1' in the declaration.  While this is an interesting challenge for an experienced VHDL person, I would impressed if someone new to VHDL were able to accomplish this - that said, I will warn you that this may be a test to see if you asked a homework question on SO.  I would recommend turning in something similar to what I recommended above as that is well within a new person's capability.

```vhdl
library IEEE ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all ; 
entity TwoClockOneProcess is 
end entity TwoClockOneProcess ; 
architecture test of TwoClockOneProcess is 
  signal Clk1, Clk2 : std_logic := '1' ; 
  constant PERIOD_1 : time := 8 ns ;
  constant DUTY_CYCLE_1 : real := 0.5 ; 
  constant PERIOD_2 : time := 5 ns ; 
  constant DUTY_CYCLE_2 : real := 0.75 ; 
begin
 ClockProc : process
    procedure LocalClock(
      signal Clk         : inout std_logic ; 
      constant Period    : in    time ; 
      constant DutyCycle : in    real 
    ) is 
    begin
      Clk <= transport '0' after Period * DutyCycle, '1' after Period ;
    end procedure LocalClock ; 
  begin
    Clk1 <= '1' ; 
    LocalClock(Clk1, PERIOD_1, DUTY_CYCLE_1) ;
    Clk2 <= '1' ; 
    LocalClock(Clk2, PERIOD_2, DUTY_CYCLE_2) ; 
    loop 
      wait on Clk1, Clk2 ; 
      if rising_edge(Clk1) then 
        LocalClock(Clk1, PERIOD_1, DUTY_CYCLE_1) ;
      end if ; 
      if rising_edge(Clk2) then 
        LocalClock(Clk2, PERIOD_2, DUTY_CYCLE_2) ;
      end if ; 
    end loop ; 
  end process ClockProc ; 
end architecture test ;
```

Comment: It's not a homework but a college work  I'm new here and I don't know if it's allowed to ask questions about university work. If it's not allowed, please let me know and I'll delete my post. Trank you

Comment: The solution above shows you a simple way and a hard way.   The hard way follows your description.   I always recommend the easy way of doing things

Comment: Independent items go in separate processes, concurrent assignments, or concurrent procedure calls.   The only reason to put them together is there is some relationship between the two which is not met when the two are running independently.